# Hash constructor parameter in 1.9.*

Tags: ruby

I seem to be having problems with using a hash parameter to my constructor in Ruby 1.9.2. I note that what I'm trying to do works in 1.8.7. Here is my example code:

```
def initialize(*params)
    @attr1 = params[:attr1] or nil
    @attr2 = params[:attr2] or nil
end
```

However, when  I try to instantiate an object of this example class, I get an error message on the line where the first instance variable is set: `in '[]': can't convert Symbol into Integer (TypeError)`

Why does this not work in 1.9.2? And how do I work around it?

Comment: The example as given doesn't work in 1.8.7 either.

Comment: watch out! you want `@attr1 = params[:attr1] || nil`, it's not the same. In any case it looks weird, if the key is not found in the hash, you'll already get `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the splat (`*`) to capture a single hash argument. It's used to capture an unknown number of arguments. Change your function definition to

```
def initialize(params = {})
    @attr1 = params[:attr1] or nil
    @attr2 = params[:attr2] or nil
end
```

and everything should work the way you'd expect. **Edit:** The `params = {}` makes the params argument optional, and sets it to an empty hash when nothing is provided.

What's actually being captured in `params` with the function definion you have now, would be like this:

```
Whatever.new(:foo => 'foo', :bar => 'bar')
# params contains [{:foo => 'foo', :bar => 'bar'}]
```

so you'd need to reach into the array first to get the hash, then use the hash keys.

When Ruby sees a set of hash key/value pairs as the last argument to a function, it's automatically wrapped into a Hash. So even though it looks like you're supplying multiple arguments to the function, the interpreter is actually only receiving a single argument.

Comment: Sorry, I added the splat operator so that I could initialize an object with no params hash as well (ie Myclass.new()). Is there any way to do this without using the splat operator?

Comment: As a simplest way, you can use optional parameters - `def initialize(params = {})`

Answer (score 5):

Because from splat `*` symbol you turn your hash actual parameter into array:

```
class Test
  def initialize(*params)
    p params
  end
end

Test.new(attr1: 1, attr2: 2)  # => [{:attr1=>1, :attr2=>2}]
```

Remove `*` from `initialize` method:

```
class Test
  def initialize(params)
    @attr1 = params[:attr1] or nil
    @attr2 = params[:attr2] or nil
  end

  attr_accessor :attr1, :attr2
end

test = Test.new(attr1: 1, attr2: 2)
test.attr1  #= > 1
```