# trying to understand specific bit of ruby syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

I'm new to both Ruby and Rails, and as I go over various tutorials, I occasionally hit on a bit of Ruby syntax that I just can't grok.

For instance, what does this actually do?

```
root to: "welcome#index"
```

I can gather that this is probably a method named "root", but I'm lost after that.  "To" isn't a symbol, is it?  The colon would be before, as in ":to" if it were.   Is this some form of keyword argument utilizing hashes?  I can't make this syntax work when trying it in irb with ruby1.9.3.

I know this might be a RTFM question, but I can't even think of what to google for this.

Thanks!

I'm still playing around with this syntax,

```
def func(h)
    puts h[:to]
end

x = { :to => "welcome#index" }
y = :to => "welcome#index"
z = to: "welcome#index" 

func to: "welcome#index"
```

I see that this example only works with the lines defining "y" and "z" commented out.  So the braceless and the "colon-after" syntax are only valid in the context of calling a method?

Comment: Symbolhound.com is sometimes useful when googling syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, that's right - `root` is a method call. 
Now

```
to: 'welcome#index'
```

is equivalent to

```
:to => 'welcome#index'
```

and it's a `Hash` where the key is `:to` symbol and value is `'welcome#index'` string. You can use this syntax in defining hashes since `Ruby 1.9`.

Answer (score 4):

It's equivalent to

```
root(:to => "welcome#index")
```

I'm having trouble finding the official documentation on the new hash syntax, but when you see `foo: bar`, it means that `foo` is a symbol used as a key in the hash and has a value `bar`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of defining a function `foo` which takes a hash, and prints to screen.

```
def foo(hash)
  puts hash.inspect
  puts hash[:to]
end

foo to: "wecome#index" #method call without paratheses
```

**Output** of method call above:

```
{:to=>"welcome#index"}
welcome#index
```

Equivalent declarations:

```
h = {:to => "welcome#index"}   
h = {to: "wecolme#index"}
```

Also, you can use [Ripper](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ripper/rdoc/Ripper.html) (part of Ruby standard library) to understand how Ruby parses code.  In the example below, I have already defined `foo` as above.  Now, I call `foo` without using Ripper.  Then I use Ripper to see how Ruby parses the method call.

```
[2] pry(main)> foo to: "welcome#index"
{:to=>"welcome#index"}
welcome#index
=> nil
[3] pry(main)> require 'ripper'
=> true
[4] pry(main)> Ripper.sexp 'foo to: "welcome#index"'
=> [:program,
 [[:command,
   [:@ident, "foo", [1, 0]],
   [:args_add_block,
    [[:bare_assoc_hash,
      [[:assoc_new,
        [:@label, "to:", [1, 4]],
        [:string_literal,
         [:string_content, [:@tstring_content, "welcome#index", [1, 9]]]]]]]],
    false]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In ruby braces in method calls are optional, so it can be rewritten as:

```
root(to: "welcome#index")
```

and it can be rewritten again as

```
root(:to => "welcome#index")
```

Hashes as keyword arguments(ruby 1.9) explained here as well: [hash-constructor-parameter-in-1-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143532/hash-constructor-parameter-in-1-9)

P.S. and by the way general rule of the thumb for the rails-newcomers is "learn ruby first, then learn rails" ;)

Comment: Re "learn Ruby first". There's a question on programmers.se about this at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158100/how-much-ruby-should-i-learn-before-moving-to-rails .

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly gathered, `root` is a method call. Or rather, it's a *message send*. Ruby, like Smalltalk, builds upon a messaging metaphor, where objects send messages to other objects, and those objects (called the *receiver*) respond to those messages.

In this case, you pass an argument to `root`, that's how you know it's a message send. Message sends are the only thing that can take arguments, if you see an argument, then it must be a message send. There are no functions, no static methods, no constructors, no procedures, only methods and message sends.

So, what *is* the argument? Well, in Ruby, a lot of things that are syntactically required in other languages are optional. For example, parenthesis around the argument list:

```
foo.bar(baz)
# can also be written as
foo.bar baz
```

If the very last argument to the message send is a `Hash` literal, you can leave off the curly braces:

```
foo.bar({ :baz => 23, :quux => 42 })
# can also be written as
foo.bar(:baz => 23, :quux => 42)
```

Put the two together, and you get:

```
foo.bar({ :baz => 23, :quux => 42 })
# can also be written as
foo.bar :baz => 23, :quux => 42
```

In Ruby 1.9, a new alternative `Hash` literal syntax was introduced. This literal syntax is very limited compared to the original one, because it can only express `Hash`es whose keys are `Symbol`s which are also valid Ruby identifiers, whereas with the original syntax, you can write down a `Hash` with any arbitrary object as key. But, for *that* limited use case, it is very readable:

```
{ :baz => 23, :quux => 42 }
# can also be written as
{ baz: 23, quux: 42 }
```

If we put that feature together with the other two, we get the message send syntax you are asking about:

```
foo.bar baz: 23, quux: 42
```

If we have method declared with a single argument like this:

```
def foo.bar(opts) p opts end
```

`opts` will be bound to a single `Hash` with two key-value pairs.

These features were often used to emulate keyword arguments as found in other languages. And it has long been a desire of the Ruby community to get support for *real* keyword arguments. This support was implemented in two steps: first, the new `Hash` literal syntax was introduced in Ruby 1.9, which allows you to make message sends which *look like* they are using keyword arguments, even though they are really just a `Hash`. And then in a second step, in Ruby 2.0 *real* keyword arguments were introduced. The modified method signature would look like this:

```
def foo.bar(baz: nil, quux: nil) p baz, quux end
```

Note that at the moment, it is not possible to have *required* keyword arguments, they *always* need to have a default value and are thus always optional. You can, however, use the fact that default values can be arbitrary expressions and do something like this:

```
def foo.bar(baz: raise ArgumentError '`baz` must be supplied!', 
  quux: raise ArgumentError '`quux` must be supplied!') p baz, quux end
```

In a future version of Ruby (it was actually already implemented in February and will likely be in 2.1), required keyword arguments can be specified by omitting the default value:

```
def foo.bar(baz:, quux:) p baz, quux end
```

Note that there is a syntactic ambiguity now:

```
foo.bar baz: 23, quux: 42
# is this sending the message `bar` to `foo` with *one* `Hash` or *two* keywords?
```

This ambiguity is actually intentional, because it allows old client code written against APIs which use a `Hash` argument to work unchanged with new APIs that use keyword arguments. There are some semi-complex rules which determine whether that syntax will be interpreted as a `Hash` or as keywords, but mostly those rules work out the way you would expect them to.